# Error en consola al ejecutar mi script personalizado de node.js llamado npm start

Tags: javascript, nodejs

He creado un comando personalizado en mi **package.json** llamado npm start que incluye tareas como gulp watch & node server.js, a la hora de ejecutarlo en consola aparece lo siguiente:

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: watch
>   /home/stephany/Documentos/tefa/Proyectos/photoawesome/package.json
>   ENOSPC
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:953:11)
>       at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1423:19)
>       at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1450:11)

Gracias espero sus respuestas!

Comment: amigo deja ver tu package.json con el script que dices

Comment: Podrías probar ejecutando el siguiente comando: `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Podría haber un problema de espacio o de permisos.

```
ENOSPC = No hay espacio en el disco
```

Quizás estés trabajando en un disco chico, en un pendrive o en un servidor que tenga una couta pequeña

Answer (score 0):

Si tu entorno de desarrollo es windows no te va funcionar asi. Yo lo solucione instalando el paquete `npm i --save-dev npm-run-all` y en el archivo package.json quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "gulp",
    "gulp-watch": "gulp watch",
    "start-server": "node server.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel gulp-watch  start-server"
  }
```

Espero te funcione

Comment: Estoy seguro ya lo solucionó, debido a que la pregunta es de hace casi 3 años :). Si tu solución es válida, está bien que la hayas puesto, para futuros visitantes. Sin embargo, trata de no revivir preguntas tan antiguas, para mantener el orden cósmico StackOverflowriano. Bienvenido a StackOverflow ;)